# PHP Classes : Call a specific function everytime a method call is made

Tags: php, oop

I want to call a function every time a method call is made in PHP.

Example :

```
$a = new a();
$a->function1();
```

this would make 2 function calls: `basicFunction()` and then `function1()`

Same would be the case for any subsequent method calls of that class. is this possible in object oriented PHP?

Comment: It's not clear, whether you want to have `basicFunction` called when `function1` is called or when the ctor is called or when any function is called. Also, is `basicFunction` part of the the `a` class? Please clarify the question and maybe add a concrete example illustrating what you need this for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest would be to just call the method

```
public function function1 {
    $this->basicFunction();
    // …
}
```

What you are probably after is something like [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). However, this is not common in PHP. The most notable use is in the [Flow3 framework](http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/manuals/flow3/flow3.aopframework/).

For other more common approaches usable with PHP OOP, have a look at

- [the Decorator pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator)
- [the Subject/Observer pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer)
- [Event Dispatcher pattern](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/)

These would allow you to add arbitrary behavior and control flow at runtime.

---

*(meta)* On a sidenote, do we really need four answers suggesting to use `__call`? I suggest the various OPs review their respective answers, sort out the tiny differences and agree on which one is best. The other three could withdraw their answers then.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like this in PHP. You can, however, simulate this behaviour using the [magic method `__call()`](http://php.net/__call):

```
class YourClass {
    public function __call($method, $args){
        // do what you want to do everywhere (i.e. call your basicFunction)
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'base'.ucfirst($method)), $args);
    }

    private baseSomeFunction() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj = new YourClass();
$obj->someFunction(); // this calls baseSomeFunction and executes the code
                      // in the __call() method
```

Prefixing your "magic" methods with something like `base` ensures that nobody can call your private functions and limits this access to only the functions that have been prefixed. You should change this prefix to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, although it involves some overhead. The magic method `_call` will handle non-existing methods so you could do:

```
class myClass {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {

        $this->doSomething();
        $this->$name($arguments);
    }

    private function calledmethod() { ... }
```

And then you'd call:

```
$class->calledmethod();
```

Since the method `calledmethod` isn't public, _call would get invoked then would run your 'base' method and then `calledmethod`.

I do feel obliged to ask, WHY do you need to do this? There's probably a more elegant solution if you'd describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I think `-` in function names in invalid.

Comment: This will not return the function output.

Comment: @elusive: fixed, too much js lately, thanks. @cypher: OP never said anything about returning a value.

Comment: I'd say that returning a value of the original called function is pretty much implied as he didn't say he wishes that no method of his function will return a value.

Comment: @Erik: `-` is allowed in variable names in JavaScript? Didn't know that. I know that you could use every string like this: `window['some-function-name']()` but that would be kind of a pain, right?

Comment: This makes _all_ private methods public.

Comment: And there is a second problem: The arguments are passed as an array instead of regular arguments.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the [__call magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)
For your example:

```
class Foo{
    public function __call($method_name, $arguments){
        $this->basicFunction();
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method_name), $arguments);
    }


    private function basicFunction(){}
    protected function function1(){}
}
```

Comment: if function1() is public, __call won't be used.

Comment: I could call _every_ private method now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__call` magic function like this:

```
class a {
  private function function1() { ... }
  public function __call($name, $args) {
       /* do stuff */;
       return call_user_func_array(array($this, $name), $args);
  }
}
```

Note however this won't work if function1() is called from inside the class. Then you'd have to rename function1() and call it with different name. The idea is that `__call` is invoked only if the function doesn't exist or can not be seen.

Comment: I could call _every_ private function of this class.

Comment: @elusive - if you're bothered by this, put some conditions into __call. It's just a suggestion, not production code :)